# Profile Field In Admin Bar

Tags: author, profiles

I have added a field named "Current Status" in the user profile where the users fill their information e.g. E-mail, Website etc. How can I make this field displayed only for authors and  also display it in the admin/author bar so they can update it without going to profile area? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_currentuserinfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) to find out a user's role. To modify the wordpress admin bar, use the [admin bar render hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render).

Comment: The problem is that I want to add an input field.. I know how to add links and menus...

Comment: What if you use similar code to [this](http://sumtips.com/2011/03/customize-wordpress-admin-bar.html) and instead of having an HTML address, have a JavaScript pseudo protocol that calls something similar to a lightbox (without fading the background).